# Compare 2 tables with reference number and update value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having trouble with SQL query (Microsoft Access) that involves comparing column and update from two table

I want to compare `tableA.com_id` and `tableB.com_id` and if they are the same, update 'TRUE' in `tableA.check` with every reference `tableA.ref_id`

tableA

> ref_id | com_id | check
>   10001 | 20001 |
>   10002 | 20008 |
>   10003 | 20005 |
>   10004 | 20001 |

tableB

> ref_id | com_id |
>   10001 | 20001 |
>   10004 | 20004 |
>   10002 | 20008 |
>   10001 | 20011 |
>   10001 | 20021 |

Desired output:

> ref_id | com_id | check
>   10001 | 20001 | TRUE
>   10002 | 20008 | TRUE
>   10003 | 20005 |
>   10004 | 20001 |

I've tried many queries, but they don't work. For example:

```
UPDATE tableA SET CHECK = 'TRUE' 
WHERE tableA.ref_id = (SELECT ref_id FROM tableB) 
 AND tableA.com_id  = (SELECT com_id FROM tableB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use a `join`:

```
update tableA
join (tableB on tableA.ref_id = tableB.ref_id and tableA.com_id = tableB.com_id) 
set tableA.Check = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: some how syntax error for the update, still the same if update tableA
join tableB on   (tableA.ref_id = tableB.ref_id and tableA.com_id = tableB.com_id) 
set tableA.Check = 'TRUE'